# jQuery PHP Chat user is typing feature

Tags: php, jquery, chat

Im use jquery for display someone is typeing.

Its ok everything work but i want everyone can see that and i cant think about something any help ?

```
var textarea = $('#input');
var typingStatus = $('#typing_on');
var lastTypedTime = new Date(0); // it's 01/01/1970
var typingDelayMillis = 1500; // how long user can "think about his spelling" before we show "No one is typing -blank space." message

function refreshTypingStatus() {
    if (!textarea.is(':focus') || textarea.val() == '' || new Date().getTime() - lastTypedTime.getTime() > typingDelayMillis) {
        typingStatus.html('');
    } else {
        typingStatus.html('<div id="new"><div class="comment" style="display:inline;"><div class="user_name"> <b><font color="white"><?php echo $pernome?> <br> <center> <b style="font-size:9px;"> <?php echo $datenow?>  </b> </center></font></b></div></div>  <div class="comment" style="display:inline; position:relative; font-size:14px; bottom:6px; color:#ffffff; margin-bottom:2px;">מקליד...</div></div>');
    }
}
function updateLastTypedTime() {
    lastTypedTime = new Date();
}

setInterval(refreshTypingStatus, 100);
textarea.keypress(updateLastTypedTime);
textarea.blur(refreshTypingStatus);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm assuming you're already using WebSockets for transmitting the text messages, so you can simply just have a second channel for sending 'X is typing...' notifications.

Comment: im use just PHP/jQuery @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Then how are the other chatters notified of new messages?

Comment: jQuery also, want me add the all code it is necessary ?
@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you research and implement websockets. What you're trying to do is possible with AJAX, but it's needlessly more complicated and puts much more strain on your server

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Its for school we need use just html/css/jquery/php
there is a way?